# Do we need to retain this exact duplicate?

Tags: discussion, deletion, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/5743/3955) is marked as a duplicate of [this one](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/5740/3955). But, I noticed that the target is completely identical to the question that is closed as a duplicate. What seems to have happened is that the OP posted the same question both here as well as on Music Practice and Theory SE, and the latter got migrated here and marked as a duplicate of the question asked by the OP here.

Although it is sometimes useful to retain duplicates, especially for the purposes of searching, it seems unnecessary to have both copies in this case. So, can we delete the question that is closed as a duplicate?

Please note that I currently do not have the reputation required to cast a delete vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree, it is the exact duplicate by the same person and it seems to add no value. Answer is also an exact duplicate by the same person. I voted for deletion.